# How to add file types to file explorer right click options in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11

I understand there are answers out there for resetting the right click context menu for file explorer in Windows 11 back to Windows 10, but I was wondering if anyone knows how to add a file type/extension to the context menu under the "New" option (like New .TXT file)?

I don't want to reset the menu back to Windows 10, I want to be able to add a file type to the Windows 11 context menu.

Anyone know how this is done?

I feel like it is possible because if you download Google Docs, you get the option to make a new google doc file type in the right click contexts menu in Windows 11 file explorer.

Comment: Have you looked in Settings, Apps, Default Apps, and scroll down the right side for Choose defaults by File Type or by Link Type?   That is the way Windows 11 does contexts.

Comment: What would you like to do with the file type/extension in the context menu?

Comment: ???  What do I wish to do?  Never mind!     A whole pile of options suddely disappeared from the right-click context-menu "NEW" option in my Win-11 system !       Where did all these options suddenly disappear to?  Now all I have left is "Folder", "shortcut" and "bitmap image" !!   Where did all the others in my "new" option disappear to?